# How to change data graph and convert a php variable to javascript from another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, forms

I am trying to change the "title text" of a graph that I am using. This graph uses data from PHP and get settings plot in Javascript. But I would like to configure my graph title through a variable from a form of other page.
In graph page I can call the selected option from the form of the other page by using $_POST['pol_list"]... So how can I transform "title" in "Selected item from the form"?
Thanks!

Here the graph code:

```
    <?php

$dataPoints = array( 
    array("label"=>"Chrome", "y"=>64.02),
    array("label"=>"Firefox", "y"=>12.55),
    array("label"=>"IE", "y"=>8.47),
    array("label"=>"Safari", "y"=>6.08),
    array("label"=>"Edge", "y"=>4.29),
    array("label"=>"Others", "y"=>4.59)
)

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {


var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Usage Share of Desktop Browsers"
    },
    subtitles: [{
        text: "November 2017"
    }],
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        yValueFormatString: "#,##0.00\"%\"",
        indexLabel: "{label} ({y})",
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the form code from another PHP page:

```
    <form action="../view/PlotaGrafico.php" method="post">
     <select name="pol_list">
       <option value="p1">Item 1</option>
       <option value="p2"> Item 2</option>
       <option value="p3"> Item 3</option>
       <option value="p4"> Item 4</option>
      <input type="submit">
     </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear what exactly you want to change? There is a lot of code in here it's unclear what specifically you want to change.

Comment: I want change the Title (where is written: "Usage share of Desktop browsers") of the graph using a PHP variable from a form, the first code is just the graph, (draw, data etc), and the second code is the form code.

Comment: You should just be able to switch the `title:` to be some kind of `$_POST[]` variable can't you?

Comment: Can't =/ because this field just can be text like: text: "TEXT HERE". I already tried to put $_POST on this field, but didn't work.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to put PHP in here without PHP tags as this is HTML. So it would need to be something like `title: <?php echo $_POST['title']; ?>`

Comment: Tried 2 ways: 

     title: { <?php echo $pol_sel; ?> 
     },

And:

     title: {
         text: <?php echo $pol_sel; ?> 
     },

Didn't work... So is it impossible to do?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. What did the resulting HTML look like after using that second one? `title: { text: <?php echo $pol_sel; ?> }`. As in what did the generated HTML look like on the page?

Comment: Nothing happens, the graph doesnt ploted.

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($pol_sel)`? Where are you setting that variable? I don't see it in your example.

Comment: Nothing too using var_dump($pol_sel). That variable is $pol_sel = $_POST['pol_list']

Comment: I think that's your problem. If you aren't getting anything when you `var_dump($pol_sel)` then that's why nothing is showing when you `echo` it, the variable isn't set.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `text: <?php echo $_POST['pol_list']; ?>` instead?

Comment: Yeah, dont work... I found this link explaning something like i want to do: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/title/set/ but instead cliking, i need to cath the information from variable $pol_sel

Comment: Yes that can be used to set the title at a later time, but your problem right now is that the `$pol_set` variable is empty. That is why the title is not working with the PHP echo. Where are you setting `$pol_set`? Ensure it is getting information properly and maybe share that code too so we can ensure it's working

Comment: The $pol_set is setting when user select an item in the form from another PHP page like this part of code that i showed: <select name="pol_list">

Comment: so i instance this such as:  "$pol_sel = $_POST['pol_list']"

Comment: And the entire graph disappear, so i think the field "text" in graph data can't acept variables, just methods.

Answer (score 0):

I got!

the element in "text" field must be a JSON.

So this worked:

```
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 title: {
     text: <?php echo json_encode($pol_sel); ?>
```

Thanks!